# CPU Usage High - Physical Memory Low on Virtual Machine (VMWare)

Tags: windows-7, memory, virtual-machine, cpu, vmware

I run a development environment in a Windows 7 VM (on VMWare) and am running into an issue in the VM where my CPU Usage sits at 100% and my Physical Memory stays around 40-50%. My computer has 24 GB of RAM in it and I allocated 8 GB to the virtual machine. The processor in my machine is an Intel Core i7-4700HQ (CPU @ 2.40GHz). What could be the issue?

Comment: Ahhhhhh....swapping?

Comment: Excuse me ignorance, but what do you mean?

Comment: which process uses the CPU? Vmware? Assign less cores to the VM to have some resources free on the host.

Comment: It's not my host machine that's having the problem, it's my virtual machine OS. And it's whatever application I have open. If I have NetBeans open, it takes up 100% CPU, if I open Chrome, that takes up 100% CPU, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into similar issues, in Windows Task Manager it shows 100% CPU usage and high memory usage in Windows 7 SP1 virtual image using vmware vSphere 5.1.0 . Even after adding more memory and CPU it would utilize whatever the system has.

After removing all Windows update on windows 7 image and manually installing them back by the type I was able to determine that Windows Security update was the root cause.

Another great tool is "Process Explorer" by Microsoft which give more details than the native Windows Task Manager.

Comment: Did you note which update? If you simply hid it, you can identify it by doing "restore hidden updates" to see a list (actually unhiding takes additional steps).

Comment: Wow, that must have been a long journey...